# CORS issues with frontend and backend running on the same VPS

Tags: go, cors, network-programming, fetch-api, vps

My setup on my VPS is the following:

- golang backend, exposing a REST API in a docker container on 127.0.0.1:6060
- svelte frontend, build with node adapter, running in a Node.js process, on 127.0.0.1:3000
- nginx as reverse proxy, using certbot for https

I use a domain (let's call it `https://example.com`), which is redirected via DNS A-Record to my VPS IP. So far so good, the frontend is running on my domain.

My nginx setting are basically these:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

plus the certbot stuff.

I use js fetch() requests to call my golang REST API. The Origin of the requests is `https://example.com`

In my backend http server i set the following Headers to handle CORS:

```
headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https:example.com")
headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
if req.Method != http.MethodOptions {
    next.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
    return
}
// process an HTTP OPTIONS preflight request
headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, allow-credentials")
```

I also use the autocert package's manager to handle https, the setup looks like this:

```
m := &autocert.Manager{
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("secret-dir"),
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        Email:      "example@example.org",
        HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("example.com", "www.example.com"),
    }

    server := &http.Server{
        // Addr: ":6060",
        Addr:      ":https",
        TLSConfig: m.TLSConfig(),
        // Set timeouts to avoid Slowloris attacks.
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 15,
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 15,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second * 60,
        Handler:      routerWithCORS,
    }
```

My GET (etc) requests call `https://127.0.0.1:6060/api/v1/whatever`, the call's origin is `https://example.com` and in the network tab of the browser i get

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://127.0.0.1:6060/api/v1/me. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I also applied this wide open nginx settings to enable CORS in nginx with no luck:

```
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
}
```

I thought i would not need https on my golang backend, as the requests come from 127.0.0.1 on the VPS and call 127.0.0.1:6060 on the very same VPS, but looking into the network tab, the origin of the calls is https://example.com. So i guess that is the main problem. I can't call a http ressource from a https origin. But even if running the backend in https does not work.

I hope there might be a less complicated solution to this problems, would appreciate help to point me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

### Configure CORS in at most one place

By configuring CORS in multiple places,

- at the application level (in your Go code), and
- at the reverse-proxy level (in your NGINX config),

you're inviting problems. CORS should be configured in at most one place, wherever it's easier and configuration changes are more likely to get reviewed.

### Favour configuring CORS at the application level

So where should you configure CORS?
Configuring CORS in a reverse proxy like NGINX can be challenging because you don't get the full expressive power of a programming language like Go. That's why I'm partial to configuring CORS at the application level.

### Rely on a proven CORS middleware

Configuring CORS by manually setting response headers is tempting but error-prone, especially if you're not intimately familiar with the protocol. Your specific case proves my point:

> ```golang
> headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https:example.com")
> headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
> if req.Method != http.MethodOptions {
>     next.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
>     return
> }
> request headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, allow-credentials")
> ```

- The first statement has no chance of working as expected since `https:example.com` is not a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin); you meant `https://example.com`.
- Contrary to popular belief, you most likely don't need to list `OPTIONS` as an allowed method.
- Another issue is that header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` has no place in responses to non-preflight requests.
- Also, not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.

All those difficulties should be enough to convince you that you're better off relying on a proven CORS middleware library, which can abstract some of this complexity away from you.

#### A solution using jub0bs/cors

I recently released [jub0bs/cors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/cors), a CORS middleware library that's designed to be easy to use and, importantly, *hard to misuse*. Here's an example:

```golang
corsMw, err := cors.NewMiddleware(cors.Config{
  Origins:        []string{"https://example.com"},
  Credentialed:   true,
  Methods:        []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost},
  RequestHeaders: []string{"Content-Type"},
})
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
// use corsMw's Wrap method to apply the CORS middleware to your http.Handler
// start your server
```

Adapt this example to suit your needs and remove everything related to CORS in your NGINX config.